# Python: how to use regular expressions to do search + replace

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a Python script in which I need to do some search and replace in some XML-like strings.

Let's say I have a string `foo` that contains some XML of the form `<bar>something</bar>`.  I want to change the `something` within the `<bar>...</bar>`, let's say to `<bar>something_else</bar>`.

How would I go about doing this?

Sorry if this is a newbie question, but I'm pretty new to Python.  I read through the Python regular expression docs but that only served to confuse me further.  (actually I find regular expressions confusing in other contexts/languages as well, so that may not necessarily be Python's fault :) )

Comment: XML or XML-like? because regex and HTML/XML are like oil and water - they don't like to mix. If it's HTML or XML, you're far better off using something like `lxml.etree` to make changes to the contexts.

Comment: I agree with isedev http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: This might be a good starting place: http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/module-xml.dom.html Once you have done your XML parsing you can do regex on the fetching strings (inside the tags) to go even deeper if needed.

Comment: If you want to replace the text inside XML tags, I'd recommend going with an XML parsing approach such as [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an trivial example of how you would do it with `lxml.etree`, to get you started along the right path (based on the comments above):

```
text = """<tag><innertag>text</innertag>more text</tag>"""
import lxml.etree
xml = lxml.etree.fromstring(text)
node = xml.find('innertag')
node.text = "new text"
lxml.etree.tostring(xml)
'<tag><innertag>new text</innertag>more text</tag>'
```

See the [lxml](http://lxml.de/) documentation.